# Distributing limit over multiplication

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I wish to evaluate the following limit

$\lim_{x \to 0} [\ln (1+(\sin x)^2)][\cot(\ln (1+x)^2)]$

Can I distribute the limit over multiplication? And evaluate the limits of both the square brackets separately?
If I am wrong how can this limit be found?

Edit : So can I rewrite it like this
$\lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{ln(1+(\sin x)^2}{ (\sin x)^2})(\frac{ (\sin x)^2}{x^2})( {\ln (1+x)}^2\cot({\ln (1+x)}^2))(\frac{x^2}{ {\ln (1+x)}^2}) $

And then apply the standard limits to get the answer 1

Comment: This works as long as both of the limits exist and are finite. You might run into trouble with something like $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\cdot\frac{1}{x}$ if you aren't careful, though.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can only distribute the limit through multiplication when both of the factors involved converge independently

Comment: Not in this example since the second term goes to $\infty$. So, in this example, one can use a host of techniques such as asymptotic analysis.

Comment: Can you specify if you mean $\cot(\ln[(1+x)^2])$ or $\cot(\ln^2(1+x))$? I assume the latter, but it is better to be sure.

Comment: Yes it is the latter one

Comment: If I cannot do so then how will I evaluate it?

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule is another way to go.

Comment: Note the following: If $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = L \neq 0$ then $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to a}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x \to a}g(x)$$ irrespective of the behavior of $g(x)$ as $x \to a$. This means that if $g(x) \to M$ then $f(x)g(x) \to LM$. If $g(x) \to \pm \infty$ then $f(x)g(x) \to \pm\infty$. If $g(x)$ oscillates then $f(x)g(x)$ also oscillates. Hence the limit can be distributed over multiplication if the limit of one of the factors is non-zero. Your approach of standard limits is the perfect way to evaluate the limit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had another doubt. Consider this $\lim_{x \to a} g(x).\cot(f(x))$ and I rewrite it as $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{g(x).\cot(f(x)).f(x)}{f(x)}$ . Suppose $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$ Now can I apply the standard limit on cot x? And what should be the restrictions on g(x) except that it should tend to a finite value as x tends to a?